# Emacs package install script cannot get packages

Tags: emacs, package

I want to use script to install all packages automatically when I move to new computer.

I write this script and emacs give me `Package ‘highlight-symbol-’ is unavailable`

```
#! emacs -q --script 
;;; load package module
(require 'package)
(dolist (url '(("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/")
           ("melpa-stable" . "http://stable.melpa.org/packages/")
       ))
  (add-to-list 'package-archives url t))
(package-initialize)

;;; read package list from `packages` file
(defvar *packages-list '("highlight-symbol" "monokai-theme"))


(unless package-archive-contents
  (package-refresh-contents))

;;; install packages
(dolist (package *packages-list)
  (if (package-installed-p (intern package))
      (princ (format "%s already installed \n" package))
    (progn
      (princ (format "%s is installing \n" package))
      (package-install package)
      (princ (format "%s installed \n\n")))))
```

What I tried:

1. Use `emacs -q` and try it into *scratch*. `(package-install package)` still has problem.
2. I don't know `DONT-SELECT` meaning in #'package-install, so I tried `(package-install package nil)` and `(package-install package "")`, they still have issues.
3. M-x package-install works well.

How can I fix it. And what is misunderstanding I made in this script.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, guys, it is a idiot question.

Answer is `package-install` accept symbol, but string.

I change code to `(package-install (intern package)` and then it works.